# spring-roo creates json controllers for wrong @id property name

Tags: json, spring-roo

I am about to evaluate spring roo whereas I am reverse engineering an existing mysql database scheme. Everything works well except the `web mvc json all` command creates in some cases `*_Roo_Controller_Json.aj` files which refer to a non existent JPA Entity getter: `getId()`. This seems to occur in cases where the field annotated with `@Id` is having a different name than id. Strangely this problem not always occurs when I create the application from scratch by executing the whole roo script (posted below).

The JPA Entity ITD looks like:

```
privileged aspect FrmwrkAuthItem_Roo_Jpa_Entity {

    declare @type: FrmwrkAuthItem: @Entity;

    declare @type: FrmwrkAuthItem: @Table(name = "frmwrk_AuthItem");

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 64)
    private String FrmwrkAuthItem.name;

    public String FrmwrkAuthItem.getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void FrmwrkAuthItem.setName(String id) {
        this.name = id;
    }   
}
```

`web mvc json all` command creates the file FrmwrkAuthItemController_Roo_Controller_Json.aj with a `createFromJson()` method in which the non existing getter `getId()` is used (code simplified).

```
privileged aspect FrmwrkAuthItemController_Roo_Controller_Json {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> FrmwrkAuthItemController.createFromJson(@RequestBody String json, UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        try {
            FrmwrkAuthItem frmwrkAuthItem = FrmwrkAuthItem.fromJsonToFrmwrkAuthItem(json);
            frmwrkAuthItemService.saveFrmwrkAuthItem(frmwrkAuthItem);
            RequestMapping a = (RequestMapping) getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

            /******************************************** 
             * below is the corrupt line of code with frmwrkAuthItem.getId()
             * frmwrkAuthItem.getName() would be correct! 
             ********************************************/
            headers.add("Location",uriBuilder.path(a.value()[0]+"/"+frmwrkAuthItem.getId().toString()).build().toUriString());

            return new ResponseEntity<String>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"ERROR\":"+e.getMessage()+"\"}", headers, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        ....
```

The roo script to create the application is:

```
project --topLevelPackage org.myproject
jpa setup --provider ECLIPSELINK --database MYSQL --databaseName myproject  --userName *** --password ***
addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.wrapping.mysql-connector-java

database reverse engineer --schema myproject --service --package ~.domain
json all
web mvc setup --package ~.contoller
web mvc all --package ~.contoller
web mvc json all
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Spring Roo version are you using?

If it's the latest, I think this problem could be a bug. Could you create a ticket in [Spring Roo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO) about it?.

For a faster resolution, you could include a backup of your project (you can use the `backup` Spring-Roo-shell command after remove user/passwd of roo.log file).

Regards.

Comment: I am using the latest Spring Roo version (1.3.1) but also could reproduce the error with version 1.2.5. I created a Jira ticket for this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3589